# What's wrong with my self-defined init method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In ClassA:

```
- (ClassA *)initWithID:(NSString *) cID andTitle:(NSString *) cTitle {
    ClassAID = cID;
    ClassATitle = cTitle;
    return self;
}
```

In ClassB:

```
- (void)cellDidSelected {
    ClassA *classAController = [[ClassA alloc] init];
//Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” when executing the following line.
    classAController = [classAController initWithClassAID:ClassAID andClassATitle:ClassATitle];
    NSLog(@"I want to get the value of ID:%@ and Title:%@ here.", [classAController ClassATitle], [classAController ClassAID])
}
```

Could anyone point where is wrong? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is `ClassA` defined? Is it a subclass of any type (speicifically one with an `init` routine)?

Comment: `    @interface ClassA : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate> { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
- (id)initWithID:(NSString*) cID andTitle:(NSString*) cTitle {

    if (!(self = [super init]))
       return nil;

    ClassAID = cID;
    ClassATitle = cTitle;
    return self;
}
```

Then you can just do something like:

```
ClassA * classA = [[ClassA alloc] initWithID:anID andTitle:aTitle];
```

And I would recommend having `ClassAID` and `ClassATitle` as properties if they're not already, and if they are you should be using:

```
[self setClassAID:cID];
[self setClassATitle:cTitle];
```

That way they'll be retained properly.

Comment: This solution should also mention the removal of the [[ClassA alloc] init] line, but is the best of those available thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the structure one would design for the situation you've posted above would include the call to `[super init]` within `initWithID` itself, so you would only have one `init` routine called per object instantiation. However I don't see that being the root cause of the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Seeing your post, I try it again, and still failed.  
I've initialed the classAController and pass it as the parameter.
Why do I still need to invoke [super init]? Thanks.

Comment: Because the super object needs to be initialised as well as your object.